# How do I set up a dedicated server for my multiplayer Unity game?

Tags: unity, networking, server

I've made a multiplayer game with Unity and Mirror networking, and it all works perfectly when just running it on my own computer. However, I am trying to host on a dedicated server so that I can put the project on my portfolio and not have to worry about whether players can log in and test/play the game or not.

I tried a AWS Free server and I see that the Tanks example from Mirror is working just fine (although laggy), but my own project doesn't. I think this has something to do with the RAM limit of the free server but I'm not sure. I can see the task manager going up to 95% memory usage. When I remove some particle effects and geometry and enemies, it works.

I'm not sure if this is my code that is so cloggy or the server or both. In any case I would need a solution for this but I don't know what my options are.

Would be great if anyone can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Your server should just execute logic. Why do you need to render particles on a server?